# Variations of the same song

Tags: production, soundtrack, terminology

What is the name of the *term* used for when the soundtrack composer, creates a song and the other songs are variations of the same song. For example, in the movie **Inception**, **The Last of the Mohicans**, **Requiem For a Dream**

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but the terms "reprise", "remix" & "alternate version" often accompany those derivative tracks in soundtracks and albums, usually in parentheses.

Comment: Do you mean like the Bond theme being used in music throughout the films?

Comment: @Walt yeah, but, I think that it isn't what I'm lookking for.
@CGCampbell nearly so. If you listen the soundtrack of `Incepction` you will understand better.

Comment: A very clear example is _The Long Goodbye_, in the film of the same name. John Williams (of Star Wars and Potter fame) created the title song, and it is rendered a number of times throughout the movie (via radio a couple times, live in the piano bar, live at the Mexican funeral, a bluesy rendition, etc.), different each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really is just called a [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_%28music%29) and it's not limited to soundtracks, Wikipedia says:

> In music, variation is a formal technique where material is repeated in an altered form.

A famous example of this are the [Goldberg Variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_Variations).

A [Leitmotif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitmotif) is by definition the leading theme of the overall piece, which would be the film in this case, so it may be the main character's theme tune, or the [title theme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_music), which is then the most likely candidate to be the tune which is varied throughout the rest of the film depending on the tone of the scene or emotional state of the character(s).

Comment: I've read about it. I also found the term `Leitmotiv`. Now, I'm confused, hehe.
http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitmoti

Comment: @FelipeStoker I've added an edit to compare the two ideas

Comment: Fun fact: when I was 14 I saw The Dark Crystal and bought the soundtrack. Turns out several songs used the same melody, just with different "moods" and orchestrations. I remember a swelling full orchestra version, as well as a lively "galloping across the plains" version. There are probably other variations that I missed (or can't recall now that I'm 46!).